Dot product of every pair of rows of a matrix
I have some code to get the cosine of the angle between vectors given by every pair of rows in a large rectangular matrix,
overlap = Compile[{{i, _Integer, 0}, {j, _Integer, 0}, {matrix, _Real, 2}},
    matrix[[i, All]] . matrix[[j, All]]/
   Norm[matrix[[i, All]]]  Norm[matrix[[j, All]]], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

and I run this with
overlap[1, 2, Table[RandomReal[{1, 2}], {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}]] // AbsoluteTiming


{0.000334, 19.6299}

This is a bit slow, I have used the built in function VectorAngle, but this is also taking hours, and I'm looking at a very large matrix so millions of pairs of rows to consider. Is there some good way to do this in Mathematica?

If you want the result for every pair of rows, would something like this work? A=Normalize/@matrix; result=A.Transpose[A]

Exactly, replace dot product with matrix multiplication as @SimonWoods suggests

Ok will try that, thanks!

Well the first simplification would be to cut half of your computation by only computing v[[i]] . v[[j]] (and never also v[[j]] . v[[i]]).  I would also use Parallelize to get another factor of 8.

FYI, you can replace your Table by RandomReal[{1, 2}, {10, 10}].
